# LaTeXで画像にリンクをつけたい

Tags: latex

`\includegraphics`コマンドで読み込んだ画像に対してリンクをつけたいです。以下の例では`\href`コマンドを使いました。コンパイルは通りますが、PDFのほうではリンクになっていません（Adobe Acrobat Reader DCで確認）。なにか特別な設定やコマンドを用いる必要があるのでしょうか？

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \href{http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pachydyptes_ponderosus.jpg}
      {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Pachydyptes_ponderosus.jpg}}
    \caption{reconstruction of New Zealand Giant Penguins (\emph{pachydyptes ponderosus}) by 
      F.~W.~Kuhnert (1865--1926). Click on the image to visit the page on Wikimedia Commons where it 
      was downloaded from.A}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

バージョン情報:

- pLaTeX2e <2020-04-12> (based on LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5)
- dvipdfmx Version 20200315

実現可能なら手段は問いませんが、なるべく今の環境のままうごく方法が望ましいです。

Comment: 対策にはなりませんが，事象としては https://twitter.com/aminophen/status/1214129200149360641 と同様で「文字が無いところは空白と見なされる」という dvipdfmx の仕様？によるものでしょうね。例のソースで生成された PDF を物凄く注意深く見ると，画像の左下に極めて小さなリンクが付与されていると思います（私は例の画像を DL するのが億劫だったので，別の画像ファイルで試しましたが，生成された PDF のストリームを読むと

  /Rect [
    133.538
    278.024
    134.534
    279.02
  ]

のように「高さ1pt，幅1pt」の枠を生成しています）。試しに \includegraphics の前後に何らかの文字を付加すると，「画像を横切るけれども，高さは文字の分だけしかない枠」が表示されます。

Comment: 独り言：よく見ると座標の差は 0.996 なので「高さ1bp，幅1bp」でなく「高さ1pt，幅1pt」だった。※72.27pt = 72bp = 25.40mm。なぜだろう？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

事象としては，dvipdfmx の「文字が無いところは空白と見なされる」という仕様（？）によるものです。対策としては「見えない文字」を左下角と右上角に置けば「文字がある」とみなされます。

以下のソースのように，囲みたいのに囲まれないものを `\GHOST{...}` という命令で囲めばリンクの枠が期待する大きさで生成します。

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% \GHOST
% This code is based on bxdpx-beamer.sty.
% Ref. 1: https://zrbabbler.hatenablog.com/entry/20130220/1361318258
% Ref. 2: https://zrbabbler.hatenablog.com/entry/20130221/1361455788
\newbox\sxamtc@ghost
\font\sxamtc@font=ec-lmr10 at 1sp
\setbox\sxamtc@ghost\hbox{\sxamtc@font\char23}
\def\GHOST#1{%
  \begingroup
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1}%
    \lower\dp\@tempboxa\copy\sxamtc@ghost
    \copy\@tempboxa
    \@tempdima\ht\@tempboxa \advance\@tempdima\ht\sxamtc@ghost
    \raise\@tempdima\copy\sxamtc@ghost
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}\centering
    \href{https://texjp.org}
      {\GHOST{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a.png}}}
    \caption{Japanese \TeX\ Development Community}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

（実装はコメント行に書いたとおり bxdpx-beamer パッケージを参照しました）

Comment: いただいたコードで無事動作しました！`bxdpx-beamer`パッケージはすでに利用していたので、次のようなコマンドでもいけそうです: `\newcommand\hrefgraphics[3][]{\href{#3}{\bxqbd@enghost{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}}`